# Vaadin 14 grid makes second request

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

When I load page with vaadin grid I see that there are two requests that load the same data. So it takes data twice what increase load time. I don't know why. I don't think so that it is caused by load next page but I don't know how to debug it.

Do you have the same problem?

Comment: How did you set the items or how did you create the DataProvider. Please show us some code

Comment: Also note, that there is with a dynamic backed provider most likely being a count and a page request. For the page request be sure to also note what page is requested. Either way: please add the code you are using and also be specific what exact requests you are seeing.

Comment: I'm using DataProvider.fromFilteringCallbacks that loads data from a DB by pageSize defined in grid (50 items by default). From browser's network log I see that second request incoming from client side. Code is more complex. My question is if this behavior is standard vaadin's grid behavior or not.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You should create a GH ticket if you can create a minimal reproducible example.